# How to get the value of a select box element by its option in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My select box is as follows:

```
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>A</option>
    <option value='2'>B</option>
    <option value='3'>C</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value of option - B without selecting it.

With jQuery I can do the opposite i.e get the text when I know the value through following:

```
$("#list option[value='2']").text();
```

But I want the reverse. I tried with following but not working:

```
 $("#owner option['B']").val();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't use "plz" or other forms of chat speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

Assuming "owner" really is the ID of your `<select>` (it's "list" in your example), you can use:

```
 $("#owner option:contains('B')").val() // 2
```

Comment: What if there is another option that also contains that value in it's text? e.g. `<option value="1000">BB</option>`

Comment: @RichardD Then you would want a different solution, obviously. Also, "its", not "it's"...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:contains(text)`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, to only get the elements that contain certain text:

```
$("#list option:contains('B')").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the right option element:

```
$("#list option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "B";
}).val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JWjKf/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var b = $("#list").find('option:contains("B")').val();
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/MxpTZ/1/

Comment: That's not what the question is asking for, they already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
  $('#list option:contains("B")').prop('value') //jquery 1.6 or later
```

oR

```
$('#list option:contains("B")').attr('value');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to get the element by position, you can do this:

```
$('#list').children().eq(1).val();
```

Comment: They want to get the element by text, not position.